# Как обратится к контролу, если его имя задано в виде текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть textbox. Его имя задано в виде текста `"textBoxName"`(он создан программно). Как обратиться к его свойствам? Например хочу что бы его text был равен `Ручка`.

Comment: `textBoxName.Text = "Ручка";`

Comment: Как создавали `TextBox`?

Answer (score 2):

Сперва вам нужно найти этот контрол в коллекции контролов родительского элемента. например, если вы создавали текстбокс и клали его в форму:

```
string textBoxName = "textBoxName";
var textBox - new TextBox()
{
    Name = textBoxName
};
this.Controls.Add(textBox);

...

var foundTextBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == textBoxName);
if (foundTextBox != null)
{
    // работаем с текстбоксом
}
else
{
    // не нашли текстбокс с таким именем
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поиск контрола по имени:

```
TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBoxName", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
tbx.Text = "Ручка";
```

[Ответ подсмотрен тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898588/find-control-by-name-from-windows-forms-controls)

Answer (score 1):

```
( Controls["textBoxName"] as TextBox).Text="Ручка".
```

вдруг кому пригодится. а так всем спасибо!